# I unable to update, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu

```
W:Ignoring file 'rohan' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
W:Ignoring file 'Untitled Document 1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
E:Type 'ain' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list
```

Comment: What did you do before it became like this?

Comment: i had installed wine tats all

Comment: do we have a solution for tat sir

Comment: I don't asked you to describe what you did, but the exact actions you made. What commands you ran, what *you did* before the problem appeared.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you accidentally messed up the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

Somehow a file called `rohan`, a file called `Untitled Document 1` were created in this directory and the file `ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list` became corrupted.

Try to remove the files `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rohan` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/Untitled Document 1` (or move them to `~/` - your homedirectory - if you are unsure if they contain any relevant data for you).

Edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list` and change `ain` to `main` on the first line (most probably the last word on the first line).

Answer (score 2):

You could ignore the first two lines, or correct the problems

1. Remove the file `rohan` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rohan
   ```
2. Remove the file `Untitled Document 1` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

   ```
   sudo rm "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/Untitled Document 1"
   ```

---

Correct the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list`

- Correct the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list`

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list
  ```

  And replace the content with the following lines

  ```
  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu precise main 
  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu precise main
  ```